# Middle button on trackpad/point doesn't work with GNOME 3

Tags: mouse, trackpad

I just upgraded my GUI from Unity to GNOME3.
There's one problem I'm having, though. Pointing Devices apparently loses functionality in GNOME3, but I need to be able to use my trackpoint.

Pointing Devices can disable the trackpad fine, and my trackpoint itself works fine, but my middle button doesn't work.

Is there any fix for this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

What I had to do was create a file in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d called 20-thinkpad.conf

Inside the file, I put:

```
Section "InputClass"
Identifier "Trackpoint Wheel Emulation"
MatchProduct "TrackPoint"
MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
Driver "evdev"
Option "EmulateWheel" "true"
Option "EmulateWheelButton" "2"
Option "Emulate3Buttons" "false"
Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```